# Get UV color with animation nodes

Tags: uv, animation-nodes

In animation nodes, there is a `Load UVs` option:
[image]

How can I access those UV's. And is there a way to check what the texture color is for a specific UV coordinate?

Comment: Do you want to get UV co-ordinates of a UV map or color value of the image based on the UV map?

Comment: @3DSinghVFX the color value for each vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is possible to get UV coordinates and UV colors but for that, you have to install **[Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes](https://github.com/3DSinghVFX/animation_nodes/tree/extranodes)** because it has **[UV nodes](https://youtu.be/HHnpax7egHM)** and **[Texture Input](https://youtu.be/0ot1CCy-MOg)** node.

**Step-1:** In this example, I'm using Cube object and its default UV map with a simple image texture,
[image]

**Step-2:** You can access the UV coordinates with the **UV Map Data Input** node. I have subtracted combine (UV coordinates) by value 0.5 to bring these vectors at the world center in 3D space,
[image]

**Step-3:** Next, add the image texture (whose color values you want at the UV vertices) as Texture,
[image]

**Step-4:** Now, we will evaluate the texture at the UV coordinates (green points) in 3D Space with the help of **Texture Input**.

[image]

**Step-5:** But, we have a small problem that Blender does not show the Texture in the 3D space and its scale. So, I have added the Vector Math (scale) and Vector Offset nodes to estimate the scale of the texture,
[image]

**Step-6:** Next, connect the Texture Input node and adjust the scale such that it should match scale in Step-1. In this example, the value of scale is 2. The output of the Texture Input node is the colors of the image at the UV vertices.
[image]

Blend File:

[image]